# How to use a compound NSPredicate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I would like to know how if at all to use a compound NSPredicate?

I have made an attempt as follows however the currentInstall array is exactly the same at the start as it is after the predicate has been applied.

```
NSArray *currentInstall = [coreDataController filterReadInstalls:selectedInstallID];
    NSArray *tempArray = [currentInstalls filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"cHR == 0"]];
    currentInstalls = [tempArray copy];

    NSPredicate *predicateAreaString = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"area == %@", [myFilter objectForKey:@"area"]];
    NSPredicate *predicateBString = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"stage == %@", [myFilter objectForKey:@"area2"]];
    NSPredicate *predicateCString = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"partCode == %@", [myFilter objectForKey:@"area3"]];
    NSPredicate *predicateDString = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"doorNo CONTAINS[cd] %@", [myFilter objectForKey:@"door"]];
    NSPredicate *predicateEString = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"doorDesc CONTAINS[cd] %@", [myFilter objectForKey:@"doorDesc"]];

    NSPredicate *compoundPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[predicateAreaString, predicateBString, predicateCString, predicateDString, predicateEString]];

    NSMutableArray *filteredArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[currentInstalls filteredArrayUsingPredicate:compoundPredicate]];
    currentInstalls = [filteredArray mutableCopy];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be anything obviously wrong with the way you have implemented `NSCompundPredicate`. If you are not trying to And or Not predicates then I would say it is something wrong with your predicate formats and how they match the array you are filtering.

I would try to use just 2 of the predicates to create an `NSCompundPredicate` then get that working or see what is causing your issue. NSHipster also has some good info about [NSPredicates](http://nshipster.com/nspredicate/).

Comment: okay I will dial it back to two then work up from there and see how it goes, it was just the first time I have ever used a compound predicate so abit lost atm.... but will keep trying.

Comment: Okay so I have tried filtering the array using a single predicate and it worked. Not really sure why the compound predicate wont work.

Comment: Turns out it works... but returns everything because I am using orPredicateWithSubpredicates, I have changed to andPredicateWithSubpredicates and it now returns the correct information.